# Remove box-shadow break while using columns in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a pinterest style layout. I've reached almost to completion but the only problem is, if you scroll to the bottom of the page, you will see the `box-shadow` breaking for the first 3 columns.

How should I avoid this?

```css
#container {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
}

.entity {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* float: left; */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

.entity:nth-child(2n) {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.entity:nth-child(2n+1) {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.entity:nth-child(3n) {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Firefox (Gecko) doesn't have this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ejq70ggp/ It may have something to do with how the rending engine "break" contents into columns. Chrome (Blink/WebKit) seems to break by "snapshot", while Firefox (Gecko) seems to break by DOM node.

Comment: With firefox all is OK, confirmed :). Chrome sucks so much, day by day much more, with his innumbered tons of bugs like this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a webkit bug as the issue is not reproducible in Firefox. There are a few (unconfirmed) webkit bug reports that have been filed for this issue [Bug 14137 - box-shadow on element inside multi-column doesn't draw outside column boundary](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14137) and [Bug 101184 - box-shadow is cropped when using column-count and column-gap](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=101184).

It would appear that Chrome is not taking the `box-shadow` into account when it moves an element into a new column. One way you could get around this is to add `margin-top` to the `.entity` `div`s. This would effectively act as reserved space for the `box-shadow` and will stop it from being split across columns.

The following modifications have been made to your code:

- `margin-top: -6px;` added to `#container` to counter act `margin-top: 6px;` set of `.entity`
- `margin-top: 6px;` added to `.entity` to act as reserved space for the `box-shadow`
- `margin-bottom` changed to `9px;` on `.entity` to keep the same space between elements

```css
#container {
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -moz-column-gap: 15px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.entity {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* float: left; */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}

.entity:nth-child(2n) {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.entity:nth-child(2n+1) {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.entity:nth-child(3n) {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
  <div class="entity"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution but your answer is faster, so I'll just post my jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ejq70ggp/1/ works in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I was just modifying the `margin`s as it occurred to me that this could look the same as the original, looks like we were both thinking on the same lines.

Comment: This trick will do for now, else it's be better to wait for a fix

Comment: you just adjust the box-shadow for remove the shadow at the bottom of three columns like using  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #d5d5d5;

Comment: The key workaround here seems to be the `display: inline-block`. Just changing the margins doesn't fix it. This necessitates the `width: 100%` as well.

Comment: This is still present in 2022...

Answer (score 4):

I did somenthing diferent and it worked for me...
This:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="entity-protection">
     <div class="entity"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Entity-protection css:`border: 5px solid transparent; break-inside: avoid;`

The point is: the div with box-shadow should be inside the protection div for avoid its break.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Adding this around each entity worked for me.

Comment: This is only working solution when `.entity` should be any but `inline-block`. In this case `.entity-protection` cound be `inline-block` and it works. Even without transparent border.